# Inject context into custom IconButton objects

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, button, dependency-injection

I'm building an app in Flutter and encountered a problem leading to code duplication. I'm trying to unify the IconButtons in the NavigationBar to be an object, so for every NavigationBar I build I can use pre-designed IconButtons and build them as a list. This means I can easily change icons and button types anywhere on the app.

The issue I'm encountering is passing the build context. I want to create the buttons without defining a build context, while still having an OnPressed() function. Example of the old button (using GoRouter):

```
IconButton(
  tooltip: 'Profile',
  icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
  onPressed: () {
    context.push('/profile');
  },
),
```

Here is my current, basic solution for this problem:

```
class CustomIconButtons {
  IconButton profileButton(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      tooltip: 'Profile',
      icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
      onPressed: () {
        context.push('/profile');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

However, this uses a function with return type IconButton, while I want to use an **object**. With the function I would need to newly build the IconButtons again on every function call, while the only thing that changes is the context. With objects I could initialize the important buttons once, and just reuse them (for example the home button is present on every page except the home page itself). How would I go about doing this?

I tried creating a CustomButtonClass, but of course it does not recognize the context. But if I inject the context into the object directly, it is inflexible to context changes. So I could not create these buttons for permanence *without* passing the context in the constructor.

```
class CustomIconButtons {
  IconButton button;

  CustomIconButtons.homeButton()
      : button = IconButton(
          tooltip: 'Home',
          icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
          onPressed: () {
            context.push('/home'); // <--- Issue
          },
        );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new StatelessWidget and pass context from the parent widget:
There is an example:

```
class CustomIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
final BuildContext context;
final String tooltip;
final Icon icon;



const CustomIconButton({
    super.key,
    required this.context,
    required this.tooltip,
    required this.icon,
  });
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(tooltip: tooltip, icon: icon, onPressed: () {
      this.context.push('/profile');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this does most of what I wanted. How would I need to modify this code to be able to create an object without knowing the context first? So I can just pass it later, but create objects without containing the context first?